# json_encode Vazio

Tags: php, mysql, json, crud

Abaixo meu codigo PHP. Ele pega os dados do banco, coloca em um array e depois passa por um json_encode. Porém, não imprime nada, como resolver?

Obs.: Usando print_r no array é possível visualizar perfeitamente os dados

```
<?php        
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "angulardb";
    $host = "localhost";
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", $user, $password, $db);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $usuario = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *  FROM users");

    if (!$usuario) {
        echo "Não foi possível executar a consulta no banco de dados: " . mysql_error();
        exit;

    }

    $return = array();

    while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuario)) {
        $return[] = $dados;

    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');   
    echo json_encode($return);

?>
Database:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `nome`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES
(2, 'João Silva', 'joao.silva@angular.com', '123456'),
(3, 'Mario de Almeida', 'mario.almeida@angular.com', '123456');
```

Comment: Se os valores que vierem do array não estiverem códificados corretamente o a função não irá fazer esta conversão, estão todos utf8 ?

Comment: `echo json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido. Aparentemente o erro estava no banco dados, especificamente no collation do mesmo. Alterei de latin para UTF8, e funcionou.

Obrigado